# click event on anchor tag that fades out ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a link that when hovered fades in an unordered list, when you click a list item within the unordered list then the ul should fade out. At the moment Im having trouble working out how this can be done. If anyone can explain to me where Im going wrong or has any useful tips about how I can make my code better that would be great.

Code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/W8AL5/

---

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container li.hover').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('ul.countries').fadeToggle(200);
    });

    $('ul.countries a').click(function() {
        $('this').find('ul.countries').fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: The whole `ul` should fade out entirely? Or the `ul` should fade out leaving the clicked `li` behind?

Comment: @David Thomas the whole ul should fade out

Answer (score 4):

Your code isn't actually that far away.  Just a couple of problems:

1. `$('this')` doesn't work. You need `$(this)`.  The `this` keyword points to the element that was clicked.
2. `.find('ul.countries')` -- [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) works on descendant elements.  The `ul` you want is a parent element.  The method you want is [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest)
3. If you want the user to stay on the same page rather than following a link, you should use [`event.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault).

So, in total:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container li.hover').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('ul.countries').fadeToggle(200);
    });

    $('ul.countries a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('ul.countries').fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W8AL5/2/)

Comment: thanks, im trying to learn jQuery and there are just so many methods Im just not sure which ones to use! I tried your code, when you click a link the ul fades out but when you move the mouse from the faded ul area a flickering effect begins?

Comment: @kyllle You need to add `.stop(true, true)`. See [update](http://jsfiddle.net/W8AL5/3/).

Answer (score 0):

find is not the right choice in your situation here.  It only searches the descendants of a jQuery element,  and in this case 'this' will always be a child of the ul you are trying to get.  [see more on find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

you can query the ul directly if you'd like:

```
$('ul.countries').fadeToggle(200);
$('ul.countries').fadeOut(200);
```